# Determine the number of times a message has been on the Azure Topic

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I currently have an azure service bus topic that I'm subscribed to and want to implement retry logic based on the number of times a message has been on the topic. Is there a method in the Microsoft.Azure package that provides us with this information? Do I need to configure the message that is received by the C# service bus subscriber client to send that information? Do I need to change anything on the topic itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Message Stats in Azure Service Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462261/getting-message-stats-in-azure-service-bus)

Comment: [Determining how many messages are on the Azure Service Bus Queue/Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210207/15969115)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT No, because that just lets me know about the number of messages on the topic/queue, not the number of times a particular message has been on a queue/topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Message.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount` property for that:

> Number of deliveries that have been attempted for this message. The count is incremented when a message lock expires, or the message is explicitly abandoned by the receiver. This property is read-only.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.systempropertiescollection.deliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-servicebus-message-systempropertiescollection-deliverycount))

If you ever switch to the newest SDK, [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/), it is the  `ProcessMessageEventArgs.Message.DeliveryCount` property, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage.deliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusreceivedmessage-deliverycount)